# In a Bayesian Model, if we know that the prior, likelihood, and posterior are all distributions, is the normalizing constant a distribution as well?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

In a Bayesian model, we normally have that:

$$
p(\boldsymbol\mu|\boldsymbol X) = \dfrac{p(\boldsymbol X|\boldsymbol \mu)p(\boldsymbol \mu)}{p( \boldsymbol X)}
$$

Now suppose that $\boldsymbol \mu \sim N(\boldsymbol \mu_0, A)$ and that $\boldsymbol X | \boldsymbol \mu \sim N(\boldsymbol \mu, B)$. In this case, by conjugation properties, the posterior, $p(\boldsymbol\mu|\boldsymbol X) $ is also normal.

Suppose now that I want to find the marginal density of $\boldsymbol X$. Then normally we would integrate $p(\boldsymbol X|\boldsymbol \mu)p(\boldsymbol \mu)$ with respect to $\boldsymbol \mu$.

HOWEVER, another method is to just use:

$$
p( \boldsymbol X) = \dfrac{p(\boldsymbol X|\boldsymbol \mu)p(\boldsymbol \mu)}{p(\boldsymbol\mu|\boldsymbol X)}
$$

and to just drop all terms not in $\boldsymbol X$, in essence, to find the kernel of $\boldsymbol X$, which should be an exponential form. After this, we just fill in the constants by way of identification of the kernel.

It appears that here this technique works. However I am wondering if in general this result holds.

**My question is:** What allows us to know that $p(\boldsymbol X)$ is a valid probability density function just by looking at the kernel? If the likelihood, posterior, and prior are all valid probability distribution functions summing to $1$, is it enough for me to just "fill" in constants by way of lookinga tthe kernel?

Answer (score 4):

[Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) is

$$ f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) =
\frac{ f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) \; f_X(x) }{ f_Y(y) } =
\frac{ f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) \; f_X(x) }{
\int f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) \; f_X(x) \;dx
} $$

where

$$
f_Y(y) = \int f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) \; f_X(x) \;dx
$$

by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). So it follows from the probability theory.

Comment: Is this dependent on the prior being proper? Also would having the kernel form in the denominator be enough to identify the distribution?

Comment: @user321627 it holds for proper probability distributions (pmf, pdf) in other cases it does not have to hold.

Comment: @user321627 moreover, if you want only to estimate the unconditional distribution of data, then why do you want to use Bayes theorem for it? Why not simply use KDE?

Comment: Sorry for posting my questin here, but I see you had answered perfectly several questions about Bauesian theorem. This answer is the best match my need. I would like to know from the formula you posted in this answer how the posterior distribution is derived in practice ? Do we apply this formula for every  $x$ value of  $X$   and every $y$ in the data ? thank you in advance

Comment: @Nizar the answer is "yes", but I encourage you to post it as a question and describe in greater detail what you understand and what is unclear.

Comment: Thank you Tim for answering on a comment,please see my question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299932/bayesian-inference-for-parameter-estimation?noredirect=1#comment570061_299932  I post a new question as you recommend.