# Bayesian inference for parameter estimation

Tags: bayesian, prior, hyperparameter

I am new in theBayesian inference domain, so sorry if my questions seem silly. However,   I realy need some help in understanding this concept, since reading the same information each time from references is useless.

As I understood, that with Bayesian inference one is able to find an "update" estimate of the parametr of  model  $F(\theta)=y$. Where $\theta$  represents the parameter and $y$ is the output.  It is stated that to use Bayesian inference one should have a prior distribution for  $\theta$  and "data" . What is meant by data? data for the output  after run with $\theta$ ? what if I have only a prior distribution of $\theta$  and a distribution of $y$ derived  by $F$ from  a sample of the prior distribution of $\theta$  ?

Comment: 1. You may get better/faster answers if you follow the usual statistical conventions (e.g. Roman letters for variables - and most common capital letters for random variables, lower case for observations on them; typically Greek letters for parameters), since people will more quickly get what you mean and won't have to modify their examples to fit an atypical notation. 2. Since when learning a new topic humans find it easier to go from the particular to the general rather than the other way, it might help you to start with a concrete example.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... (i) In the first instance, consider inference on say the mean of an exponential random variable (where your data would consist entirely of $y$-values); (ii) then perhaps consider something like a regression, where your data would consist of y's and predictor variables (traditionally denoted by $x$'s)

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for you answer. For me, I read some examples [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0809/eshky.pdf), even though there is some thing not clear for me. How they derive the postirieor distribution practically? Since the postirior distribution is defined as a conditional distribution, then it is related to each value of $y$, thus it is defined to each single value of $y$ in the data ?!

Comment: (Thanks for the edits).  No, you'd normally put the $y$'s all in together (condition on all the data -- i.e. compute $p(\theta|\mathbf{y})$). With concrete examples it would be possible to show you a typical calculation in one or two simple cases. I think there are some already on site, but I may be able to show you one or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a simple concrete example; it might help focus your questions.

The aim is to start with what you know/understand about the parameters $\mathbf{\theta}$ before you see these data (summarized as a prior) and then update that knowledge with the observed data.

Consider inference on a single parameter, $\mu$ in the model

$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\mu} e^{-y/\mu};\, y>0, \, \mu>0$

where $Y_1,Y_2,...Y_n$ are i.i.d draws from $f_Y$. We observe values $y_1,y_2,...y_n$ (in this case, these are our data).

In this case I'll take the easy shortcut of assuming a nice prior so that the calculations are easy. (This is simple convenience, it's not necessary to make such choices.)

Let our prior $p(\mu)={\frac {\beta ^{\alpha }}{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\mu^{-\alpha -1}e^{-{\frac {\beta }{\mu}}}$, where $\beta=10$ and $\alpha=2$. This prior has a mean of 10 but its variance isn't finite.

Let $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$

\begin{eqnarray}
p(\mu|\mathbf{y}) &\propto& f(\mathbf{y}|\mu)\,\cdot\,p(\mu)\\
 &\propto& \,\prod_i \frac{1}{\mu} e^{-y_i/\mu}\:\cdot\: \mu^{-\alpha -1}e^{-{\frac {\beta }{\mu}}} \\
 &\propto& \,\mu^{-\alpha -1}e^{-{\frac {\beta }{\mu}}} \mu^{-n} e^{-\sum_iy_i/\mu}\\
 &\propto& \,\mu^{-(\alpha+n) -1}e^{-\frac{1}{\mu}({\beta }+\sum_iy_i)}
\end{eqnarray}

We can recognize this as an inverse gamma density with parameters $\alpha+n=n+2$ and ${\beta }+\sum_iy_i=\sum_iy_i+10$. So that's our posterior distribution for $\mu$. As $n$ grows large the posterior becomes more concentrated (and the peak moves slowly toward $\bar{y}$), and less skew.

Of course it's not necessarily just parameters you may be interested in making inferences about; you may be interested in prediction, for example.

In practice you can extract information about the posterior without it necessarily being a distribution you can identify. We then either need some way of evaluating the denominator in Bayes theorem that I pushed into the proportionality constant: $\int_\mu f(\mathbf{y}|\mu)\,p(\mu)\,d\mu$ - perhaps by numerical methods - or we may have some way of avoiding evaluation of that integral altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I still did not get why you choose the data points  $y_1, \cdots, y_n$  from i.i.d  $Y_1, \cdots,Y_n$. For me I assume we did the experiment $F$ several times at each time I get $y_i$ as an output. From these  $y_i$'s I extract the distribution of  $Y$.  So using these  $y_i$'s can I use Bayesian inference to find the posterior distribution ?

Comment: @Nizar because you assume that the variables are i.i.d.

Comment: Nizar -- You're doing the same thing I am, I am just making it clear in my notation what's going on. Your plan is to draw from $F\,$ $n$ times. Each draw will yield a random variable. I simply label those variables $Y_1$, $Y_2$, etc. but they're all draws from $F$. Once you observe them we're talking about [realizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(probability)) and we denote those by lower case equivalents. Consider if you need to talk about the distribution of $\frac{Y_1}{Y_4}\times (Y_2-Y_5)^{Y_3}$. If you don't label them you're going to be very confused.

Comment: Thank you for your patience answering all my questions  !